# Intranet file manager

Tags: php, intranet

I am developing an Intranet which will host users' files. Basically a cloud hosting for users files within the home network. I am developing this with PHP.

Is there any good file managers for intranets, which are open source? Or is there any way I can open a directory on a server within Explorer/Finder via a link on the intranet? So users can visually see their files?

Comment: Can I ask why you think this is a good idea? Why are the users files not on a file server? Is this server backed up? Do you need to secure it such that User A cannot see User B's documents? Does this need to authenticate against something like Active Directory?
I just can't see why you're trying to re-invent the perfectly functioning wheel that is NTFS permissions on a file server.

Comment: That comment is like saying why use sharepoint?  Plenty of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Hi what I believe you want is a system supporting WebDAV.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) is a set of methods based on the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) that facilitates collaboration between users in editing and managing documents and files stored on World Wide Web servers.

Here are some examples of webdav file managers:
http://www.webdav.org/projects/

Here is an open source php project:

http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/

Also it is worth noting a lot of systems allow users to map a network drive to a webdav application.  Essentially you could map H: to http://intranet/my-files

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by 'an intranet which will host user's files'? It would be useful to know why you're not using a fileshare (as per Ben's comments) in order to shape any suggestions.

There's a few solutions out there but as a MS shop we tend to just use sharepoint which means I can't comment on which ones are good. Having said that, you might take a look at [alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. I want a website where user's can view their files and basically use it as a mini cloud within home.

Comment: You'll probably think i'm being a jerk now but what does "mini cloud" mean to you? It's a great phrase to throw at management but you can't build a service out of it. A cloud like Google Docs or Office 365? Just an "online storage space"? (in which case, see Alfresco or the suggestions Iain and Pablo have made).

Comment: Well, just a low performance and somthing that just does the job. If you know what I mean lol. Sorry I'm new to all this server stuff.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [PHPFileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/). I've used it in the past to allow a group of people access to a webserver.